# Unable to Loop Cut Odd Shape

Tags: mesh

I created this odd shape through multiple loop cuts and extrusions, merged the faces (`F`) so I can start with a "clean slate". Now I'm unable to loop cut straight across this new face.

By loop cut I mean `CTRL` + `R` so if that's the wrong name for it let me know.

[image]

What are the rules to loop cutting? Why can't I cut across this new face?

Comment: because you must have ngons or ripped edges and the loop can't continue. Also there are inner faces, you probably don't want them but it's another problem. Can you share your file so that we take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cannot make a loop cut is because your front faces are n-gons (faces with more than 4 vertices).

[image: Ngon]

You can fix it by using the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>) to connect the loose vertices and make them into quads.

[image: KnifeTool]

Once it's done (all faces are quads), you will be able to make a loop cut.

[image: QuadLoop]